# How to update existing nested object properties based on a list of key-value items

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have an array of changed value including the keys and the values. So the idea is to loop through it and update new value based on key name. But the issue is that I don't know which depth the key belongs to. I guess there may be some solution using lodash but I don't know which one. Anyways, there could be better approach besides my initial attempt, any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

```js
function updateNestedObj({ obj, nodeId, value, accumulator}){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        let oldVal = obj[key]
        accumulator[nodeId] = value
        const hasChild = typeof oldVal === 'object'
        if (hasChild) 
           accumulator[nodeId] = updateNestedObj({ obj: oldVal, 
           nodeId, value, accumulator })
       
    })
}

let changedNodes = [
    { id: 'grand_child_1', value: 'new grand_child_1 value' },
    { id: 'node_child_1', value: 'new node_child_1 value' },
]

let objToBeUpdated = {
        root_node: {
            node_child: {
                grand_child: 'grand_child value',
                grand_child_1: 'grand_child_1 value',
            },
            node_child_1: 'node_child_1 value',
        },
    }

let accumulator = {}
let result= {}

changedNodes.forEach(node => {
    updateNestedObj({
        obj: objToBeUpdated,
        nodeId: node.id,
        value: node.value,
        accumulator: accumulator,
    })   
})
result.root_node=accumulator
console.log(result)
```

Expect result should look like this:

```
{
    root_node: {
        node_child: {
            grand_child: 'grand_child value',
            grand_child_1: 'new grand_child_1 value',
        },
        node_child_1: 'new node_child_1 value',
    },
}
```

Comment: what is `let obj = { ...` (line 17) within `changedNodes.forEach(node => { ...`  (line 16) good for?

Comment: oh, it should have named that variable better. It is supposed to be the object that will have its value change.

Comment: I thought so, but why is it part of the `forEach` callback

Comment: oh shit, yeah it should be outside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple recursion of walking up the tree and looping over the objects.

```js
var myObject = {
    root_node: {
        node_child: {
            grand_child: 'grand_child',
            grand_child_1: 'new grand_child_1',
        },
        node_child_1: 'new node_child_1',
    },
} 

let changedNodes = [
    { id: 'grand_child_1', value: 'new grand_child_1 UPDATED1' },
    { id: 'node_child_1', value: 'new node_child_1 UPDATED2' },
]

function updateNode(obj, key, value) {
  if (obj[key] !== undefined) { // if value can be undefined, this would need to change.
    obj[key] = value;
    return true;
  } else {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      if (obj[prop] && typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
        const result = updateNode(obj[prop], key, value);
        if (result) return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

changedNodes.forEach(({id, value}) => updateNode(myObject, id, value))
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Why updateNode function needs to return true in this case? btw, this solution seems working. Pretty simple.

Comment: @ThienLy ... the downside of this approach is that for a a lot of changes in mostly/mainly deeper object structures it is really not performant. One does not want to walk for each to be updated key value pair of the `changedNodes` list deep into an object structure again and again. Ideally  one wants to walk the tree exactly once, and rather for each node wants to do the search for a possible update.

Comment: @ThienLy so it can exit out without visiting any more locations.

Comment: @PeterSeliger It could be modified easily to check against a list and pop them off as they are found. That way too has some performance issues where you are doing a lot of checks to see if the key is in a new list. The ideal solution really depends on the real world data. In this case, it is small enough it does not matter. Plenty of ways to also keep track of nodes visited and make a look up before scanning.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Scott that we should aim to divide the program up into more sensible parts. We can write recursive `update` that accepts an input tree, `t`, a property to updated, `id`, and the value to set.

Using mathematical induction, we can structure the program in a reasonable way. The numbered points below correspond to numbered comments in the program -

1. If the property to update, `id`, matches a key, `k`, return the value to set, `value`
2. (inductive) `id` does not match the key. If a value, `v`, is an object, recursively `update` the value
3. (inductive) `id` does not match the key and `v` is not an object. Return the value unmodified

```
const update = (t, { id, value }) =>
  map
    ( t
    , (v, k) =>
        id === k
          ? value                      // 1
      : Object(v) === v
          ? update(v, { id, value })   // 2
      : v                              // 3
    )
```

This depends on a generic `map` function which allows for *mapping* over objects -

```js
const map = (t, f) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).map(([k, v]) => [k, f(v, k)]))
```

Given an original `input` and a list of `changes` -

```js
const input =
  {root_node: {node_child: {grand_child: 'grand_child value', grand_child_1: 'grand_child_1 value'}, node_child_1: 'node_child_1 value'}}

const changes =
  [{id: 'grand_child_1', value: 'new grand_child_1 value'}, {id: 'node_child_1', value: 'new node_child_1 value'}]
```

We can easily obtain the `result` using `reduce` -

```js
const result =
  changes.reduce(update, input)
  
console.log(result)
```

Output -

```
{
  "root_node": {
    "node_child": {
      "grand_child": "grand_child value",
      "grand_child_1": "new grand_child_1 value"    // <--
    },
    "node_child_1": "new node_child_1 value"        // <--
  }
}
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
const map = (t, f) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).map(([k,v]) => [k, f(v,k)]))
  
const update = (t, { id, value }) =>
  map
    ( t
    , (v, k) =>
        id === k
          ?  value 
      : Object(v) === v
          ? update(v, { id, value })
      : v 
    )

const input =
  {root_node: {node_child: {grand_child: 'grand_child value', grand_child_1: 'grand_child_1 value'}, node_child_1: 'node_child_1 value'}}

const changes =
  [{id: 'grand_child_1', value: 'new grand_child_1 value'}, {id: 'node_child_1', value: 'new node_child_1 value'}]

const result =
  changes.reduce(update, input)
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {
    root_node: {
        node_child: {
            grand_child: "grand_child value",
            grand_child_1: "grand_child_1 value"
        },
        node_child_1: "node_child_1 value"
    }
};
const changedNodes = [
    {
        id: "grand_child_1",
        value: "new grand_child_1 value"
    },
    {
        id: "node_child_1",
        value: "new node_child_1 value"
    }
];

function update(obj, changes) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (value && typeof value === "object") {
            return [
                key,
                update(value, changes)
            ];
        }
        if (changes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return [
                key,
                changes[key]
            ];
        }
        return [
            key,
            value
        ];
    }));
}

console.log(update(obj, changedNodes.reduce((obj, {id, value}) => Object.assign(obj, {[id]: value}), {})));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach uses the altering, complementary recursion of two functions.

While the first one operates any item of the *next children level* of any given object tree and also does trigger the second function, the latter either looks for a possible item update or, in case of an available *next children level*, recursively passes back to the former one that again will operate any item of this very object level ... and so on ...

```js
function isObjectObject(type) {
  return (/^\[object\s+Object\]$/).test(
    Object.prototype.toString.call(type)
  );
}

function updateObjectItemViaBoundConfig(key) {
  const { parentItem, updateList } = this; // `this` equals bound configuration.

  const currentItem = parentItem[key];
  const updateItem = updateList.find(item => (item.key === key));

  if (updateItem) {

    const { value } = updateItem;
    if (isObjectObject(value)) {

      parentItem[key] = Object.assign({}, value);
    } else {
      parentItem[key] = value;
    }
  } else if (isObjectObject(currentItem)) {

    // ... altering, complementary recursion ...
    updateObjectEntriesRecursively(currentItem, updateList);
  }
}
function updateObjectEntriesRecursively(obj, entryUpdateList) {
  // ... altering, complementary recursion ...
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(updateObjectItemViaBoundConfig, {
    parentItem: obj,
    updateList: entryUpdateList
  });
}


const sampleObject = {
  root_node: {
    node_child: {
      grand_child: 'grand_child value',
      grand_child_1: 'grand_child_1 value'
    },
    node_child_1: 'node_child_1 value'
  }
};

const changedNodes = [{
  key: 'grand_child_1',
  value: 'new grand_child_1 value'
}, {
  key: 'node_child_1',
  value: 'new node_child_1 value'
}];


updateObjectEntriesRecursively(sampleObject, changedNodes);


console.log('sampleObject :', sampleObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case one needs to update a huge amount of object nodes, the next code iteration introduces an additional argument that flags whether one wants/needs to mutate the array which contains the update-items. It does so by splicing the currently updated data from its array. Thus one might gain a tiny bit of performance, due to an ever shrinking list that, with each time it got shrunk, can be searched faster ...

```js
function isObjectObject(type) {
  return (/^\[object\s+Object\]$/).test(
    Object.prototype.toString.call(type)
  );
}

function updateObjectItemViaBoundConfig(key) {
  // `this` equals the bound config object.
  const { parentItem, updateList, isMutateList } = this;

  const currentItem = parentItem[key];
  const updateIndex = updateList.findIndex(item => (item.key === key));

  if (updateIndex >= 0) {
    const updateItem = updateList[updateIndex];
    const { value } = updateItem;

    if (isMutateList) {
      updateList.splice(updateIndex, 1);
    }
    if (isObjectObject(value)) {

      parentItem[key] = Object.assign({}, value);
    } else {
      parentItem[key] = value;
    }
  } else if (isObjectObject(currentItem)) {

    // ... altering, complementary recursion ...
    updateObjectEntriesRecursively(currentItem, updateList, isMutateList);
  }
}
function updateObjectEntriesRecursively(obj, updateList, isMutateList) {
  // ... altering, complementary recursion ...
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(updateObjectItemViaBoundConfig, {
    parentItem: obj,
    updateList,
    isMutateList
  });
}


const sampleObject = {
  root_node: {
    node_child: {
      grand_child: 'grand_child value',
      grand_child_1: 'grand_child_1 value'
    },
    node_child_1: 'node_child_1 value'
  }
};

const changedNodes = [{
  key: 'grand_child_1',
  value: 'new grand_child_1 value'
}, {
  key: 'node_child_1',
  value: 'new node_child_1 value'
}];


// updateObjectEntriesRecursively(sampleObject, changedNodes);
updateObjectEntriesRecursively(sampleObject, changedNodes, true);
// updateObjectEntriesRecursively(sampleObject, Array.from(changedNodes), true);

console.log('sampleObject :', sampleObject);
console.log('changedNodes :', changedNodes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it simpler to separate the object traversal code from that which does the actual changing of the values.  So with two simple functions, we can write this fairly nicely:

```js
const transform = (fn) => (obj) =>
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) 
    .map (([k, v]) => Object(v) === v ? [k, transform (fn) (v)] : [k, fn (k, v)])
  )
    
const mapIds = (changed) => { 
  const keys = new Map (changed .map (({id, value}) => [id, value]))
  return (k, v) => keys .has (k) ? keys .get (k) : v
}

const changedNodes = [{id: 'grand_child_1', value: 'new grand_child_1 value'}, {id: 'node_child_1', value: 'new node_child_1 value'}]
const objToBeUpdated = {root_node: {node_child: {grand_child: 'grand_child value', grand_child_1: 'grand_child_1 value'}, node_child_1: 'node_child_1 value'}}

console .log (
  transform (mapIds (changedNodes)) (objToBeUpdated)
)
```

- **`transform`** recursively traverses your object and updates leaf key-value pairs by calling the function you supply to it.

  For instance,

  ```js
  const upperCase = (k, v) => 
    typeof v == 'string' ? v .toUpperCase () : v

  transform (upperCase) (objToBeUpdated)  //=>
  // {
  //     root_node: {
  //         node_child: {
  //             grand_child: "GRAND_CHILD VALUE",
  //             grand_child_1: "GRAND_CHILD_1 VALUE"
  //         },
  //         node_child_1: "NODE_CHILD_1 VALUE"
  //     }
  // }
  ```
- **`mapIds`** takes a list of `{id, value}` objects and returns a function that takes a key and a value, and returns the matching value from that list if it's there or the original value otherwise.

  For example:

  ```js
  mapIds (changedNodes) ('grand_child_1', 'grand_child_1 value') //=> 'new grand_child_1 value'
  mapIds (changedNodes) ('foo', 'bar') //=> 'bar'
  ```

Combining them by passing `changedNodes` to `mapIds` and passing the resulting function to `transform`, we get a function that will take your object and apply these changes to your object.

We can also use them to write a custom function if we prefer:

```js
const updateObj = (changedNodes, obj) =>
  transform (mapIds (changedNodes)) (obj)

updateObj (changedNodes, objToBeUpdated) //=>
// {
//     root_node: {
//         node_child: {
//             grand_child: "grand_child value",
//             grand_child_1: "new grand_child_1 value"
//         },
//         node_child_1: "new node_child_1 value"
//     }
// }
```

There are many extensions possible to this idea.  Here we transform only leaf nodes, but it wouldn't be hard to instead return a `[key, value]` pair and transform any node we need to.  We also don't handle arrays in this version of transform.  It would be straightforward to add them.  There's also an argument for separated the callback function to `transform` into two: a predicate which determines if a node needs to be transformed and a second one to do the actual transformation.    Again, it should be simple to do.  But this should be enough to solve the immediate problem.